# String giving error jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making lightbox with jquery ui dialog, and I tried to set up it so that when an image is clicked, a dialog opens with the image inside.

```
$("img").click(function(){
   var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
   var lightBx = '<div class="img-dialog" title="' + imgSrc + '"><p><img src='" + imgSrc + "'></p></div>';
   $("body").append(lightBox);
   $(".img-dialog").dialog("open");
});
$(".img-dialog").dialog({
   autoOpen:false,
   width:400,
   height:400
});
```

However I am getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`
Why isn't this working?

Comment: Check double quotes and single quotes again.

Comment: `var lightBx = '<div class="img-dialog" title="' + imgSrc + '"><p><img src="' + imgSrc + '"></p></div>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make

```
 var lightBx = '<div class="img-dialog" title="' + imgSrc + '"><p><img src='" + imgSrc + "'></p></div>';
```

to this

```
var lightBx = '<div class="img-dialog" title="' + imgSrc + '"><p><img src="' + imgSrc + '"></p></div>';
```

Comment: I only realized my mistake when  the coloring of the code was the brownish color, instead of black, when I posted the question. My entire code editing suite amounts to a _textarea_, so I have a lot of trouble with things like this.